# Scrape website with login/pass (with static url?)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am doing a self-project to keep learning and practicing with python3. I have done some other scraping proyects using BS4 and selenium but in this project I would like to do it with BS4.

In this project, I want to scrape some data from [this site](http://sol.brainaid.de/sailonline/toolbox/). The **first problem** I am facing is that I need to be logged in to get the data. For this test I am using a usser and password provided by the website, so you could use the same credentials. Also you must select a "race" from the form ( I choosed Manilla - Calbayog).

With the inspector I detect the the info I need to pass to the post function:

```
<input name="boat" type="text" />
<input name="key" type="password" />
<select name="race">
<option value="1159">Manilla - Calbayog</option> 'This is the one I want to check for the test
```

And this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
login_data = {'boat':'sol','key':'sol','race':'1159'}
s = requests.session()
post = s.post('http://sol.brainaid.de/sailonline/toolbox/', login_data)
r = requests.get('http://sol.brainaid.de/sailonline/toolbox/')
page = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

When I check the print output I can see that I am in the same login place.

Assuming that I could login correctly would come the **second problem**...When you are logged in, a new menu appears in button shapes. The one where the data I need to scrape is in "Navigation". The thing is that when you press the button the new info appears in the browser but the url does not change, no matter where you click, the url is always the same. So, how do I get to there?

And **final problem**. I assume I am in the "Navigation" section (without using a url). I need to refresh that info at least every 30 sec. How can I do that if there is no url to request?

¿Is there any way to do this without using selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page loads data dynamically through Ajax, the url with XML data of boat is `http://sol.brainaid.de/sailonline/toolbox/getBoatData.php`, you can check it in Firefox/Chrome network inspector. All you need is token, which is stored in cookies upon login:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

login_data = {'boat':'sol','key':'sol','race':'1159'}
login_url = 'http://sol.brainaid.de/sailonline/toolbox/login.php'
boat_data_url = 'http://sol.brainaid.de/sailonline/toolbox/getBoatData.php'

with requests.session() as s:
    post = s.post(login_url, login_data)
    data = {'boat': 'sol', 'race': '1159', 'token': s.cookies.get_dict()['sailonline[1159][sol]']}
    boat_data = BeautifulSoup(s.post(boat_data_url, data=data).text, 'xml')
    print(boat_data.prettify())
```

This will print:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BOAT>
 <LAT>
  N 14°35.4000'
 </LAT>
 <LON>
  E 120°57.0000'
 </LON>
 <DTG>
  381.84
 </DTG>
 <DBL>
  107.68
 </DBL>
 <TWD>
  220.48
 </TWD>
 <TWS>
  4.76
 </TWS>
 <WPT>
  0
 </WPT>
 <RANK>
  -
 </RANK>
 <lCOG>
  COG
 </lCOG>
 <lTWA>
  &lt;u&gt;TWA&lt;/u&gt;
 </lTWA>
 <COG>
  220.48
 </COG>
 <TWA>
  000.00
 </TWA>
 <SOG>
  0.00
 </SOG>
 <PERF>
  100.00
 </PERF>
 <VMG>
  0.00
 </VMG>
 <DATE>
  2018-07-25
 </DATE>
 <TIME>
  12:47:11
 </TIME>
</BOAT>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I understood how you did it and how to find the cookie! But one last thing, if I want to avoid creating a new cookie every 30 secs (I want to update the info every 30 sec), it would be correct to do a While loop right before the line `boat_data = BeautifulSoup(s.post(boat_data_url, data=data).text, 'xml')` ?

Comment: @DLA You have various possibilities: a) using `time.sleep()` and wait 30 seconds in while loop, b) storing cookies in file and loading them upon running of script, c) doing nothing - creating new cookies has no impact how this script works ;)